# Fork function doesnt execute child process code

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int show_dir_content(char *path);

int show_dir_content(char *path)
{
    char readbuffer[80];
    char buffer[150];
    char uzun[9999];
    int totalfound = 0;
    DIR *d = opendir(path);
    if(d == NULL)
        return -3;
    struct dirent *dir;
    int piper[2];
    pid_t typer = 0;

    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        pipe(piper);
        typer = fork();

        if(typer == 0)
        {
            close(piper[0]);
            if(dir->d_type != DT_DIR)
            {   // if the type is not directory  blue
                // printf("%s\n",dir->d_name);
                sprintf(buffer, "%s", dir->d_name);
                write(piper[1], buffer, (strlen(buffer) + 1));
            }

            else if(dir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
                    strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0) // if it is a directory

            {

                char d_path[255]; // here I am using sprintf which is safer than
                                  // strcat
                sprintf(d_path, "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
                show_dir_content(d_path); // recall with the new path
            }
            exit(0);

            close(piper[1]);
        }
        else if(typer > 0)
        {
            close(piper[1]);
            read(piper[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
            // strcat(uzun,readbuffer);
            // close(piper[0]);

            break;
        }
    }

    while(wait(NULL) > 0)
        ;
    closedir(d);
    // printf("%s x_x\n",uzun);
    return totalfound + 1; // finally close the directory
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    show_dir_content(argv[1]);

    return (0);
}
```

It doesn't execute on forked child, only on parent and only once.
I use Linux Mint 18 and gcc comes with it.
i don't what causes it, it doesn't seems to be Segmentation fault because it exits correctly. I would be more then happy if anyone can see my errors here

I'm debugging on CLion.

Comment: thats not problem

Comment: Only one `fork` apply because you `break` the loop. And the child does write on your pipe (at least on linux with gcc). So I don't understand your problem.

Comment: i edited that still it doesnt get into fork

Comment: I still cant see my debug process on fork even it gets into code somehow

Comment: Hold on. You're asking because your debugger doesn't enter the code for the child?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes it doesnt debug on debugger. but i guess it works on one process?

Comment: Yes, since fork creates an entirely new process, you won't enter that code in the process you are currently debugging...

Comment: For me, the child process gets to read the `.` entry and exits because of that without writing anything to the pipe.  The parent process breaks out of the loop after reading the `.` entry too.  So, nothing useful is done by the code, but the code does what you've told it to do.  Rethink your loops and exits and breaks.  (Add diagnostic printing — it quickly shows what's up.  Add code to print whatever the child sends to the parent so you know what's going on there.)